# Project running at http://10.0.0.2:8080 but could not connect using wget?

Tags: reactjs, ubuntu, webpack

My project is running at http://10.0.0.2:8080/ but I cannot connect using wget. When the same is running at http:localhost:8080 wget is able to connect.

[image]
[image]

Comment: which port u r searching 80 or 8080?

Comment: oh Sorry. I made a blunder here. Thanks!